# Logo with text in thanks section

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I want to do something like this:

```
\title{Some title\thanks{\begin{tabular}{cl}\includegraphics{eu_logo} & This work has received funding from the European..... \end{tabular}}}
```

but I always got an error. 
I don't want the logo inline because the text in the second column may take two or more lines.
How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a way to obtain the desired result:

```
\title{Some title\thanks{
\parbox{.1\textwidth}{
\protect \includegraphics{eu_logo}
}
\parbox{.9\textwidth}{
This work has received funding from the European.....
}
}
}
```

Comment: While this is a solution such code snippets are not always useful